# Performance implications of changing NSManagedObject instances that I never intend to save

Tags: objective-c, core-data, rollback

I have a CoreData-based application that retrieves data about past events from an SQLite persistence store. Once I have the past events my application does some statistical analysis to predict future events based on the data it has about past events. Once my application has made a prediction about future events I want to run another algorithm that does some evaluation of that prediction. I'm expecting to do a lot of these evaluations, so performance optimization for each evaluation is likely to be critical.

Now, all of the classes I need to represent my future event predictions exist in my data model, and I have NSManagedObject subclasses for most of the important entities. The easiest way for me to implement my algorithms is to "fill in" the results for future events based on the prediction, and then run my evaluation using NSManagedObject instances for both the past events and the predictions for future events. However, I typically don't want to save these future event predictions in my persistent store: Once I have performed my evaluation of the prediction I want to throw away the predictions and just keep the evaluation results. I can do this pretty easily, I think, by just sending the rollback: message to my managed object context once my evaluation is complete.

That will all work fine, and from a coding perspective it seems like it will be quite easy to implement. However, I am wondering if I should expect performance concerns making such heavy use of managed objects when I have no intention of ever saving the changes I'm making. Given that performance is likely to be a factor, does using NSManagedObject instances for this make sense? Surely all the things it's doing to keep track of changes and support things like undo and complex entity relationships come with some amount of overhead. Should I be concerned about this overhead?

I could of course create non-NSManagedObject classes that implement an optimized version of my model classes for use when making predictions and evaluating them. That would involve a lot of additional work, including the work necessary to copy data back and forth between the NSManagedObject instances for past events and the optimized class instances for future events: I'd rather not create that code if it is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Surely all the things it's doing to keep track of changes and support
>   things like undo and complex entity relationships come with some
>   amount of overhead.

Core Data doesn't have the overhead that people expect owing to its optimizations. In general, using managed objects in memory is as fast or faster than any custom objects and management code you write yourself.

> Should I be concerned about this overhead?

Can't really say without implementation details but most likely not. You can hand tweak Core Data for specific circumstances to get better performance.

The best approach is always to start with the most simple solution and then move to a more complex only when ***testing*** reveals that the simple solution does not perform well.

Premature optimization is the root of all evil.